# RewriteRule in .htaccess to rewrite query parameters like path/X to script.php?parameter=X

Tags: .htaccess

This is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule ^profiles/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=profile&c=search&min=$1 [L,NC]
```

When I request:

```
profiles/0
```

What should I do to get the result as follows:

```
profiles?min=0&max=100
```

or

```
profiles/?min=0&max=100
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're after. If my edit doesn't reflect what you mean, just revert my changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing rule already is on track. You must only change `index.php?...` to `profiles`

```
RewriteRule ^profiles/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profiles?min=$1&max=100 [L,NC]
```

If you want to have only numeric values, restrict the regular expression to

```
RewriteRule ^profiles/([0-9]+)$ profiles?min=$1&max=100 [L,NC]
```

Comment: It does not work that way. https://www.website.com/profiles/?min=0&max=35 I need to have a link in this manner

Comment: What URL is entered into the browser? And what script/URL should be executed?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: mod_rewrite/RewriteRule is a tool to change the request from a client to something else. I want to know what the requested URL is (client/browser) and what the server should do (the something else part).